# Can't access text into td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

Hi all I've to access the td text of a particular column:

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
<td id="myId">HELLO WORLD</td>
//var x = $("#myId").text();
//var x = $("#myId").html();
//var x = document.getElementById('myId').innerText;
alert(x);
```

I've tried different solutions but none of them work.

[Here's the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/7SkeT/)

How can I solve it? Thanks

Comment: `HELLO WORLD` is not a text?

Comment: @Franky Can you expand your code sample a bit. As it stands it's not valid HTML and you don't have a script tag. Is this as the code appears in the page? You might also improve your Question title.

Comment: create full table, not just cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use valid HTML in order to access the values. I've updated your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7SkeT/1/).

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="myId">HELLO WORLD</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have valid HTML.

This code works for me:

```
<html>
<body>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="myId">HELLO WORLD</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div id="test"></div>
<script>
var x = document.getElementById('myId').innerText;

document.getElementById('test').innerText = document.getElementById('myId').innerText + "...";
alert(x);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

You can try it at https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6943408/25063416.html

Answer (score 0):

You just need to have have a well built html table like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="myId">HELLO WORLD</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Check the updated [feedle](http://jsfiddle.net/7SkeT/2/)